# Is there exists any tool for generating a JavaScript Unit test from spying in on running code, say in browser?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I understand that taking time and thinking to write tests with proper assumptions is important. However something like this can serve as starting boilerplate code.

For example , consider a function

```
function sum(a,b) {
  return a+b;
}
console.log(sum(3,4));
console.log(sum(0,2));
```

so we inject/include a function , i.e it listens 
in on the input given to sum while it is running(like [dojo connect](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/connect.html), listens in on the arguments object for expected inputs and the result of the function for the expected output) and auto generates the test cases.

so the tool will automatically generate tests as

```
describe("sum tests", function(){
    SpyOn(sum);
    expect(sum(3,4).to.Equal(7));
    expect(sum(0,1).to.Equal(1))
})
```

If something like this doesn't exist , I was thinking to attempt to build a basic version of this myself. I guess for complex inputs as objects ,may need to create spies for function call. ex -

```
sum.apply(null, Source.getInputs()).
```

so now need to mock the Source.getInputs function. 
What other complications I may need to take into account in that case ?

Comment: What you might be looking for is Data Driven Testing. If you are using Jasmine, you can try out [Jasmine Data Driven Tests](https://github.com/gburghardt/jasmine-data_driven_tests), a plugin I wrote to solve these sorts of problems. Cross site duplicate with alternative solution as well: [How would one test a function with a large number of scenarios?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/323207/how-would-one-test-a-function-with-a-large-number-of-scenarios)

Comment: ah this does look interesting. as I can understand particularly to create several configurations of input. however it doesn't automatically create tests for you by listening on the live running code I guess ?

Comment: Correct. You'll still have to write the test case, but at least you can define the test case once and throw different data at the same test.

Comment: Searching for **javascript data driven testing** should give you more suggestions for other plugins for many of the popular testing frameworks. You aren't just locked in to Jasmine.

Comment: alright thanks for your help. I will search around more. btw what is your opinion about the utility of such a tool if it was created ?